# use cat and grep to look for a bunch of files and give me info while retaining file name

Tags: grep, cat

so I am running the following command
cat /Users/sars/logs/testlogs/2012-04-02*/*/top |grep -H "httpd"

I'm using the * because there are a bunch of directories (which is actually the information I am looking for) and looking for the phrase httpd in the top output

But when I do this I get (standard input): 4951 root         1  96    0 14052K  6844K select  2   0:12  0.00% httpd
instead of the filename

how do I go through these directories look in the top file and find the lines with httpd in them while maintaining the name and path of the file it is found in?

Answer (score 0):

`grep` can take the filenames as arguments:

```
grep -H "httpd" /Users/sars/logs/testlogs/2012-04-02*/*/top
```

Comment: i tried that but it doesn't return anything.  when I try the command above it returns results but with standard input instead of filename

Comment: I believe grep -l returns the filename but it might suppress the contents.

Answer (score 0):

`ack` is a good tool for this sort of thing, but is nonstandard.  To do it with grep, you probably want to use find:

```
find /Users/sars/logs/testlogs -type f \
    -wholename '/Users/sars/logs/testlogs/2012-04-02*/*/top/*' \
    -exec grep -H httpd {} \;
```